# ASP.NET/C# equivalent to js alert() or php echo

Tags: 2010, debugging

I am trying to debug a method and need to trace how a variable is being changed to see where I went wrong. What in ASP.NET/C# could I use to do this?

For example if it was php I could stick an `echo` where ever I need to check the value and it would print it to the html. JavaScript I could use `alert(var);`

Comment: Can't you use normal debug in Visual Studio? Set a breakpoint in left margin and hit F5.

You could also use SPLog ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.upgrade.splog.aspx ) and keep an eye on ULS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When on a developing machine set a break point and simply use the debug option of Visual Studio. Enable "Tracing" might also be a valuable topic to read into.

If not on a developing machine. Consider into using a logging framework. There are several free frameworks available in .NET that are highly configurable.

- http://log4netlog4net.sourceforge.net/
- http://nlog-project.org/

When in a SharePoint context consider logging errors to the ULS or the event viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just write the value to a label on the page.

Page:

```
<asp:Label ID="test" runat="server" />
```

Code-Behind:

```
test.Text = myVar.ToString();
```

-OR-

```
test.Text = "myVar: " + myVar.ToString();
```

Comment: This works well for our team on smaller projects as well.

Comment: I only use this in situations where I can't use the VS debugger, but it's quick and easy. Used to do this a lot more with classic ASP apps...

Comment: Yes, we use it in situations where we are testing on a server without VS installed (Test, Prod) and setting up a custom logging solution is more hassle than it's worth.